# Add a String to an array of Strings if it is not already present

Tags: java

I am trying to compare a string to an array of strings and add the string to the array if it is already not in the array.

I tried

```
String [] array =new String [100];
for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
    if(!str.equals(arry[i])){
        array[i]=str;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work. 
So basicaly if `array = (mike, john, tom, bob);`
and the new string is `tony`, it is supposed to compare `tony` to the array and add it to the array. But if the next string is `mike`, not add it to the array as it is already in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array has a fixed size, so adding an element to an array is not something easy. The behavior that you want is exactly the behavior of a `java.util.Set`. Learn how to use the standard collections : they're much more powerful than arrays. If you want to preserve the order of the elements, then use a LinkedHashSet. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/.

Now, why does your code fail?

You're iterating through the array, and as soon as you find one element that is not equal to the string, you replace it with the string. And you also iterate without taking the length of the array in consideration. Here's the code you might want :

```
boolean found = false;
for (String element : array) {
    if (str.equals(element)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    // add str to array, but where? Use a Set instead.
}
```

Comment: Thnak you very much. exactly what I was trying to do. I just didn't know how to write it. I am still learning java so I will need to do a lot of research. Thanks Every body

Answer (score 3):

The size of an array cannot be changed in Java. You should use a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), or, if order does not matter, a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arry));
if (! lst.contains(str)) lst.add(str);
```

Comment: thanks for the responce. That would work but I would be using ArrayList. what if my array is is defined

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I don't follow. `ArrayList` is highly optimized, and the right tool for this job. I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "what if my array is is defined".

Comment: @phihag: Why using a List if the goal is to forbid duplicates? Use a Set instead.

Comment: @phihag: if order matters, use a LinkedHashSet: no duplicates, and maintains order.

Comment: @JBNizet Added that 4 seconds after your comment ;) Maybe order *does* matter, and/or duplicates *can* occur in the input, and he just wants to ensure that certain elements are always present.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid arrays if you can, Java's [Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) is so much less trouble:

Keep all your names in a [`HashSet<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if order is important, as JB Nizet mentioned in a comment) and just `add()` **every** "next name" you come across -- the set semantics will keep all elements unique and it even grows as needed, no need to create a new array and copy things around yourself.

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
names.add("mike");
names.add("john");
names.add("tom");
names.add("bob");
assert names.size() == 4;

names.add("bob");
assert names.size() == 4; // still, because "bob" was already in the set

names.add("tony");
assert names.size() == 5; // "tony" is a new unique value, so the set grows
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) to solve this problem. A Set is a data structure which cannot contain duplicate elements and is aptly suited to your problem.

```
 Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
 Collections.addAll(names, "Mike", "John", "Tom", "Bob");
 names.add("Tony");
 System.out.println(names); // Tony gets added to the end of the Set
 names.add("Mike");
 System.out.println(names); // Set already contains Mike, don't add another
```

Output

```
[Mike, John, Tom, Bob, Tony]
[Mike, John, Tom, Bob, Tony]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
Set<String> first = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arry));
first.add(str);
```

You don'n need to control if it already exist.